# Перемещение JS-ом DIV блока в зависимости от разрешения дисплея

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру кодинга. 
Прошу сильно не пинать, я не программист, на любительском уровне знаю HTML, сделал сайт на Wordpress, это для меня первый опыт. Процент отказов доходит до 80%, потому я решил основательно переработать блоки на странице и внедрить «Полезное» «Вам будет интересно» в сайдбарах.

Изначально был один сайдбар `id="secondary"` , я добавил второй `id="leftbar"`  и тут начался взрыв мозга, который я пытаюсь решить уже неделю. 
Шаблон я в своё время выбрал адаптивный, его и дорабатываю.

**Изначально** я хотел сделать так, причём на чистом HTML\CSS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но понял, что это **весьма проблематично** на чистом HTML\CSS. Теперь я думаю сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне очень не хочется отказываться от идеи переместить левый сайдбар в левую область. Как это можно реализовать через JS?
Типа с **1025px** переносить левый сайдбар (DIV блок) в левый край страницы? С JS не знаком вовсе, если можно, то с некоторым объяснением что и куда вставлять. 
На всякий случай в очередной раз отмечу, что дизайн адаптивный (резиновый), и, к примеру, может меняться при перевороте гаджета (смарт, планшет).
Также думаю будет важным сказать, что jquery.js подключен на всех страницах.

На всякий случай прикладываю семпл страницы https://jsfiddle.net/3ypmy3o4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно, используйте Flexbox в CSS. Прочитайте [руководство](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
С его помощью довольно легко сверстать ваш изначальный макет. Обратите внимание на свойства flex-wrap и order.

Сделал [пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/indieveed/pen/EZJwWO).

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="left-sidebar">Left</div>
    <div class="right-sidebar">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}

html, body, .wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.left-sidebar,
.right-sidebar,
.content {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: azure;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 2;
  order: 1;
}

.left-sidebar,
.right-sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-sidebar {
  order: 0;
}

.right-sidebar {
  order: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .header {
    background: blue;
  }

  .main {
    display: block;
  }

  .content {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 60%;
  }

  .left-sidebar,
  .right-sidebar {
    min-width: 33%;
    float: right;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .header {
    background: red;
  }

  .main {
    display: block;
  }

  .content {
    float: none;
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
  }

  .left-sidebar,
  .right-sidebar {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись. Я попробовал Flexbox адаптировать под свой шаблон со сложной структурой, но у меня ничего не вышло. Всё съезжает и убегает непонятно куда. Я уже неделю с этим мучаюсь, с утра до вечера, глаза ломит незнамо как. Сказать что это влияет на мотивацию, то это ничего не сказать. Уже хочется просто бросить блог с 10 посетителями в сутки и забыть всё это как страшный сон 
Может всё таки коротенький JS есть? Который вставил задал стиль откуда и что перемещать и забыть всё это как страшный сон!!!

Comment: обновил ответ, добавил ссылку на codepen